# MongoDB/ExpressJS -- remove document by _id when ObjectID is contained in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
app.delete('/:id', function(req, res){
  var removal = req.params.id;
  MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, function(err, db){
    var test = db.collection('test');
    test.remove({ _id: ObjectId(removal) });
  });
});
```

But when I try that, it throws an error because ObjectId is not defined. I'm having some trouble with this one because when I use item._id in my Jade view, it just returns the number, but then of course it won't take back just the number when querying the collection for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well did you define ObjectId as a function?

try:

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
```

(The same way you got a reference to `MongoClient`)